# Window Scrolls to top when the captcha verifcation pop up is loaded (Google NoCaptcha Recaptcha)

Tags: recaptcha

I have no captcha recaptcha control at the bottom of the page. Whenever pops up a verification window asking to enter captcha text, the page scrolls to the top which is annoying.

I have to scroll to the bottom again to enter the captcha text and then click on verify button. Is there a way to avoid page from scrolling when the verfication pop up shows up ?

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EuuF3cHwDs8/VO4I8YrEmaI/AAAAAAAAAEw/-_hWmUDkOJo/s320/2015-02-25_2309.png

Comment: Same problem here. I have a form in an iframe. There is a reCAPTCHA at the bottom of the form. When I click on the "I'm not a robot" checkbox, the page is scrolled to the top. Not only the iframe, but the whole page. When I scroll down to the capthca again, I see the pop up containing 9 images.

Comment: Seems like the scripts for recaptcha have been fixed.
Check this google group thread!!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/AhAngBeuZDY

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now. :)

Comment: I have single page site, captcha widget is at bottom most of page, even `html{height: auto !important;}` not working for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726230/window-scrolls-to-top-when-the-captcha-verifcation-pop-up-is-loaded-google-noca

Answer (score 2):

1. Apparently there was a bug on Google's end which [they claim to have fixed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/recaptcha/AhAngBeuZDY/xQXECmS93sMJ).
2. Others, such as myself, continued to see this problem and discovered it was being caused by setting `html` to `height: 100%`.  Remove this line or set it to `auto`.

   ```
   html {
       height: auto;
   }
   ```

Comment: yes, height:auto !important; And it helps also if no html style was set before